# Openbox won't start with 5 GPUs. How to investigate?

Tags: ubuntu, openbox, fglrx

I have a headless server ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64 with Xorg, Openbox and amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64 drivers installed. It works just fine with 1-3 GPU, but with 4 or 5 Openbox usually hangs when starting. It starts usually after a random number of reboots, restarts or resets and then works for a couple of days until a power outage or something. Today it just plainly refused to start at all.

How do I go about investigating it? What to look for in logs?

Comment: Have you tried swapping cards around to ensure one of them isn't faulty? Like do 3 of them always work together and remain stable, regardless of which 3?  Are you sure you're providing enough power for all those GPUs + the rest of the system?

Comment: @techi Well, it can work several days without an issue. And it doesn't require a lot of power when booting. I'm not hoping for an answer to my problems right away, I just want to understand first if it's possible to deduce something useful from logs.